# Licencing implications for libraries and reference implementations

Tags: licensing

This is mostly a theoritical question, but I'm wondering what the proper way would be to accomplish the following.

Assume I have a few utilities, functions, and reference implementations that I use when building a web site for a client.  Some of "my" reference code is re-used as-is, some is slightly modified.  Also, as part of the agreement with the client, I agree to turn over all code and IP rights.

(I know the best answer is probably "talk to a lawyer" but really, how many lawyers are going to be versed in software licencing?  I imagine I'd get better, more accurate here than picking a lawyer out of the phone book).

What sort of copyright notification and/or licencing should I include in the code I turn over to the client, if I want to be able to re-use "my" code on other projects?

Comment: Talk to a lawyer who specializes in intellectual property. :-D

Answer (score 2):

Check out NOLO's "Legal Guide to Web & Software Development." It covers various contracts, license agreements, and IP ownership agreements related to software development. I have used the sample contracts as a template for a few of my agreements which are later reviewed by my attorney.

At the very least this book can help you understand what the terms, like transfer of IP ownership, really mean for you the developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn over the "IP rights", doesn't that imply you are transferring ownership of the code? Which would mean that you can't re-use it without their permission or license, since you no longer own it?

You might want to look into revising your agreements with your clients, so that you can retain ownership and rights to your own work...